# Best open source flv player for actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, flv

Need to customize the scrubbing code  for an flvplayer. I'm aware of the OSMF project, but I need to target FP9.

Anyone care to make a recommendation?

Answer (score 1):

Adobe has release a standard media player for embedding media into a webpage-- http://www.adobe.com/products/flashmediaplayback/

It is free but not open-source. If you really need an open-source version there is [Strobe Media Playback](http://www.osmf.org/strobe_mediaplayback.html).

Answer (score 0):

I've only ever used it once and that was a while ago, but I remember [JW Player](http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/jw-flv-player) being decent.